# While importing sendgrid mail it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid

I wanted to send mail using @sendgrid/mail but while I was importing it it is not working. My Code snippet is as below,

```
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

function sendMail(msg) {
  sgMail.setApiKey("API-KEY");
  sgMail.send(msg, (err, result) => {
    if(err){
        console.error(err);
    }

    console.log(result);
  });
}

const obj = {
    to: "mail@gmail.com",
    from: "no-reply@gmail.com",
    subject: "abc",
    text: "abc",
    html: "<h1>Working</h1>",
}
sendMail(obj);
```

This is the code I've did, so now the problem is sgMail.setApiKey is not a function error pops.

If I remove setApiKet then sgMail.send is not a function error pops.

So, If you have any solution then let me know.

Comment: Have you did this npm install --save @sendgrid/mail

Comment: yes i did it already

Comment: The package is in `commonjs` format. Use either `const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail')` or try default export `import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'`

Comment: sendMail(obj); change to sendMail(obj, sgMail); and function sendMail(msg, sgMail)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code this is from npmjs website refer [npmjs sendgrid/mail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail)

```
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'test@example.com',
  from: 'test@example.com',
  subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
  text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
  html: '<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js</strong>',
};
sgMail.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 23):

If you look at the [source](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/mail/index.js) of what you are trying to import, you'll find it exports a default instance of `MailService` and a named export of the class itself. When you import via:

```
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';
```

All the exports from that file are exported as a new object (`sgMail`). There are a few ways you can keep this syntax and still do what you want:

```
// use the default instance which is exported as 'default'
sgMail.default.send(obj); 
// explictly create your own instance
const svc = new sgMail.MailService();
svc.send(obj);
```

However, there is an easier way, and it's simply import the *default* instance directly

```
import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail'
```

Comment: after ```import sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';``` then either of the following works: ```sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);``` or 
```new sgMail.MailService().setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);```

Comment: One day I will understand how ES6 imports work, and it is probably going to be when the new way is out

Comment: JS imports are a history of failure. No other language has such a complicated import structure.